# How to solve set of coupled non-homogeneous partial differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Which methods can be used for analytically solving following set of coupled non-homogeneous PDE?

$$a\ddot{y_{1}}+by^{(4)}_1+c(y_1-y_2)=k_{1}(t)\delta(x-x_1),$$
$$d\ddot{y_{2}}-e{y_{2}}''+f(y_2-y_1)=k_{2}(t)\delta(x-x_2).$$

Initials and boundary conditions are

$$y_1(0,t)=y_1''(0,t) =y_1(l,t)=y_1''(l,t)=0, 
 y_2(0,t)=y_2(l,t)=0, $$
$$ y_i(x,0)=y_{i0}(x), \dot{y_{i}}(x,0)=z_{i0}(x), i=1,2.$$
In here;

$ \ddot{y_{i}}(x,t)=\frac{\partial ^2y_i(x,t)}{\partial t^2}$ for $i=1,2$.
 $y^{(4)}_1=\frac{\partial^4 y_1}{\partial x^4}, {y_{2}}'' =\frac{\partial ^2y_2}{\partial x^2}$

$a,b,c,d,e,f\in \mathbb{R} $ and $\delta$ is Dirac-Delta Distrubution.

I will be very glad, if you share your valuable suggestions. Also, I am waiting your books and article suggestions to study about this kind topics.

Thank you very much.